# Specify axios response data type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I'm building the API to connect my react app with my backend service and I want to use typescript to specify the type of `data` inside my Axios request. How can I update the type of data inside Axios response without modifying the other fields (see getAllProjects in the code below)?

```
class MyApi {
   constructor(token: string | null) {
     let headers: any = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     };
     if (token) {
        headers = {
          ...headers, //append other basic proprieties
          'Authorization': 'Token ' + token
        }
     }

     this.baseEndpoint = axios.create({
        baseURL: `${baseURL}`,
        headers: headers
     });

  }

  //DATA
  const getAllProjects = async () : Promise<AxiosResponse<?????>> => this.baseEndpoint.get('/projects/');
}
```

Simply assigning the desired type (suppose `data: string[]` for this example) throws the following error:

```
Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.
  Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try

```
export const getAllProjects = async () => backend.get<string[]>('/projects/')
```

For additional context, Axios requests are typed as the following:

```
request<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T>> (config: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<R>
```

Where an `AxiosResponse` is defined as being

```
export interface AxiosResponse<T = any>  {
  data: T;
  status: number;
  statusText: string;
  headers: any;
  config: AxiosRequestConfig;
  request?: any;
}
```

This allows them to take a generic type parameter that can be used to specify the type of the `data` property of a given response, like so:

```
type Data = {
  A: string
  B: number
  C: boolean
  // Etc.
}

Axios.get<Data>(endpoint).then(response => {
  const { data } = response // Data
  data.a // string
  data.b // number
  data.c // boolean
})
```

Comment: Thanks, Arman. I saved your answer since it's the right response to my question. The error I was making is that I haven't specified the type of my state in the UI, and the issue was not related to the Axios type.